# How to create multiple additional columns from dataframe and add to the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to parse 'date' column into 'month', 'day', 'hour' and 'minute' and then add them as separate columns to the same dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'date':[pd.Timestamp('2019-03-01 00:05:01'),
             pd.Timestamp('2019-04-02 07:11:00'),
             pd.Timestamp('2019-05-03 10:25:00')], 
     'foo': ['abc','def','jhk']
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)

    date                foo
0   2019-03-01 00:05:01 abc
1   2019-04-02 07:11:00 def
2   2019-05-03 10:25:00 jhk
```

After extracting 'times':

```
times = df1['date'].apply(lambda date: (date.month, date.day, date.hour, date.minute))
```

I try to add them to the dataframe as separate columns:

```
df1['month'], df1['day'], df1['hour'], df1['minute'] = times
```

Which results in error:

```
 ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-21-171174d71b13> in <module>
  ----> 1 df1['month'], df1['day'], df1['hour'], df1['minute'] = times

 ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)
```

How to add 'times' as separate columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want

```
df1['month'], df1['day'], df1['hour'], df1['minute'] =  (df1.date.dt.month, df1.date.dt.day, 
                                                        df1.date.dt.hour, df1.date.dt.minute)
```

---

```
print(df1)

date  foo  month  day  hour  minute
0 2019-03-01 00:05:01  abc      3    1     0       5
1 2019-04-02 07:11:00  def      4    2     7      11
2 2019-05-03 10:25:00  jhk      5    3    10      25
​
```

Comment: When dataframe 'assign' method is better to use then dot notation in your solution?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use `pd.assign`:

```
df1.assign(month=df1["date"].dt.month, day=df1["date"].dt.day, hour=df1["date"].dt.hour, minutes=df1["date"].dt.minute)
```

Output:

```
                  date  foo  month  day  hour   minutes
0   2019-03-01 00:05:01 abc     3     1    0          5
1   2019-04-02 07:11:00 def     4     2    7         11
2   2019-05-03 10:25:00 jhk     5     3   10         25
```

Comment: When 'pd.assign' is better to use then dot notation?

Comment: @dokondr There is actually no `pd.assign`, `assign` is a function of the DataFrame object: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html